# how to quit firefox by using extensions quit firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, quit

I'm not familiar with firefox extensions.Now I want to write an extension to quit firefox. How to quit firefox by using extensions?Could someone help me?Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure extensions don't have that kind of power over Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You may find help on this [reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/How_to_Quit_a_XUL_Application):

If you want to forcequit everytime you can do:

```
var appStartup = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1'].
 getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup);

appStartup.quit(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup.eForceQuit);
```